# jQuery - get reference to this

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function Request(params)
{
    // Stuff stuff stuff

    // And then

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'someurl',
        success: this.done
    });
}

Request.prototype.done = function()
{
    // "this" in this context will not refer to the Request instance.
    // How to reach it?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could capture "this" first:

```
function Request(params)
{
    // Stuff stuff stuff

    // And then

    var $this = this;

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'someurl',
        success: function() { $this.done(); }
    });
}
```

Comment: For this specifik purpose, a "context" parameter can be added to the ajax request, referencing to this. But otherwise, your solution is more general, and therefore I set it as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you can add the "context" parameter to the ajax request, like so:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'someurl',
    success: this.done,
    context: this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not reffering to the same thing!!!

Answer (score -1):

try following:

```
function Request(params)
{
   var that = this;
```

....

```
Request.prototype.done = function()
{
   that...
```

Comment: "that" is local for the Request-function.

Comment: yeah, I'm using "that" trick when inside the same "closure" to not lose reference to this; tried it also it doesn't work with prototyping. It would work if done wouldn't be defined using prototype :).

Comment: it would only work for an inline function (using closures). Using a prototype or not doesn't make any difference

Comment: function Request(params)
{
   var that = this;
this.done = function (){ that... }

....
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'someurl',
        success: this.done
    });
this is what I meant with closures.